# docker network in bridge mode

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I have been planing to install docker, but as we know the default docker networking is in `NAT` mode so it has own IP on `docker0` interface which is `172.17.42.x`.

I want to reconfigure networking in full bridge mode so all my containers get an IP address from my `LAN Wireless Router` I am following this [article](http://straightedgelinux.com/blog/howto/docker.html) and gave it a try, but it didn't work.

I have a question:

How will the container get an IP address? Or do I need to manually assign Local LAN IP address to docker container?

Or is there any better method to connect container to Local LAN so other people can access docker container?

## EDIT:

If I add a bridge interface `br0` and attach it to `eth0`, I won't able to ping outside. I am using `brctl` command to attach `br0` to `eth0`.

Comment: You need to be a little more detailed about what did not work. Broadly it is the correct approach.

Comment: Have you seen pipework?  you could use --net=none and assign an IP with pipework.

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742807/docker-1-10-containers-ip-in-lan and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488637/docker-assign-ip-from-the-same-range-as-host#autocomment59566143

Comment: Maybe a little bit more effort to tune your spelling... [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) are the most important things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you might take is to create a virtual bridge, on which you put the external interface of your host and to which you have to attach your docker containers.
Then, run your container in privileged mode and run `dhclient` in it, so that it asks your DHCP for an IP address. In this way your container should get dynamically its IP address as every normal host does.

PS Remember to run them with `--net=none`.

Here you can find a reference from which you can draw your inspiration: https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

Comment: Thanks now i am able to setup `bridge` and it works! but now i am tying to expose `port 80` of container to outside world not working :( `iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -d 182.xx.xxx.xx/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.151:80`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand very well how your networking environment is and what is the behaviour you want to have. It would be nice to have a picture reprsenting it if possible, otherwise I might say you wrong or useless things.

Comment: How does this work with net none? That causes no eth0 to be created in the container for dhclient to use...

Comment: You have to configure it manually. If you do not put `--net=none`, the container is attacher to the Docker virtual bridge. If you want to attach it to another one, you should do it by yourself... At this link (https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#container-networking), you can find an example of how to do this...